# Use tabularray in xsim template

Tags: expl3, tabularray, xsim

Is there a way to use `tabularray` in the `xsim` `ExerciseTableTemplate`? I copied the [default template](https://github.com/cgnieder/xsim/blob/9829f958161d42f9cd645ee60d953bfbff3f3213/code/xsim.definitions.code.tex#L266-L309) from xsim, just replacing `tabular` with `tblr` which results in an error I cannot make sense of:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim,tabularray,expl3}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExerciseTableTemplate {mydefault}
  {
    \XSIMputright \ExerciseTableCode
      {
        \toprule
        \XSIMifblankF { \ExerciseType }
          { \XSIMmixedcase { \GetExerciseParameter {exercise-name} } }
        &
        \XSIMmixedcase { \XSIMtranslate {points} } &
        \XSIMtranslate {reached} \\
        \midrule
      }
    \ForEachUsedExerciseByOrder
      {
        \XSIMifeqT {#1} { \ExerciseTableType {#1} }
          {
            \XSIMifblankT { \ExerciseTableType {} }
              {
                \XSIMputright \ExerciseTableCode
                  {
                    \XSIMmixedcase
                      { \ExerciseParameterGet {#1} {exercise-name} ~ }
                  }
              }
            \XSIMputright \ExerciseTableCode
              { #3 & \XSIMifblankTF {#5} {\printgoal{0}} {\printgoal{#5}} & \\ }
          }
      }
    \XSIMputright \ExerciseTableCode
      {
        \midrule
        \XSIMtranslate {total} &
        \XSIMifblankTF { \ExerciseType }
          { \TotalExerciseGoal {points} {} {} }
          { \TotalExerciseTypeGoal { \ExerciseType } {points} {} {} } &
        \\ \bottomrule
      }
    \XSIMexpandcode
      {
        \noexpand \begin {tblr} {\XSIMifblankTF{\ExerciseType}{l}{c}cc}
          \noexpand \ExerciseTableCode
        \noexpand \end {tblr}
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\gradingtable[template=mydefault]
\begin{exercise}[points=4,bonus-points=1]
    A first example for an exercise.
\end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

> Error: Misplaced alignment tab character &.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `tabularray`'s `expand` option. Replace

```
\XSIMexpandcode
  {
    \noexpand \begin {tblr} {\XSIMifblankTF{\ExerciseType}{l}{c}cc}
      \noexpand \ExerciseTableCode
    \noexpand \end {tblr}
  }
```

by

```
\XSIMexpandcode
  {
    \noexpand \begin {tblr} [expand=\noexpand\ExerciseTableCode] {\XSIMifblankTF{\ExerciseType}{l}{c}cc}
      \noexpand \ExerciseTableCode
    \noexpand \end {tblr}
  }
```

or by

```
\XSIMifblankTF{\ExerciseType}
  { \begin {tblr} [expand=\ExerciseTableCode] {lcc} }
  { \begin {tblr} [expand=\ExerciseTableCode] {ccc} }
  \ExerciseTableCode
\end {tblr}
```

`tabularray` complaining about an ”unexpandable ” `\XSIMifblankTF` is strange as`\XSIMifblankTF` actually is fully expandable, but...

Comment: I assume it is enough to replace `\noexpand` with `exp_not:V` before `\ExerciseTableCode`, instead of using `expand` option.

Comment: At present `tabularray` will not expand any macro in its inner/outer specifications arguments (see also this [issue](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/207))

Comment: The complaint was from the step when `tabularray` was expanding column type definitions. Actually a macro can not be a column type defined with `\NewColumnType`.

Comment: @L.J.R `\exp_not:V` might well be sufficient but in the example the expl syntax is superfluous in the first place... It seems it is only used to ignore spaces... So I avoided expl code

Comment: `csvsimple` package provides `\csvexpval` command to users. Maybe `xsim` could provide a similar macro? It would be perfect if the default template still works after replacing `tabular` with `tblr`.

Comment: Hi, sorry to post a message under a different answer. I read the manual chemmacros but I didn't see anything about spacing the oxidation numbers above an element. I attach this link with the hope that I can get some clarification as well. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/670899/fitting-oxidation-numbers-above-elements-without-overlapping/670949?noredirect=1#comment1667761_670949    Best regards.