# Fitting oxidation numbers above elements without overlapping

Tags: fonts, math-operators, chemistry, size, chemmacros

I want to make oxidation numbers above an element but the numbers keep overlapping in my case. I am searching for a practical solution. Maybe it would help if I managed to make the operator (- and +) shorter for oxidation numbers. It also looks to me as if the spaces between the roman letters could be smaller. How can this be fixed?

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\chemsetup[redox]{pos=top,explicit-sign=true,explicit-zero-sign=true,format=\tiny}
\begin{document}
\ch{"\ox{3,X}" "\ox{-3,B}" "\ox{3,C}"}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did about 50 or so tests to fix your code. The solution that I attach I think is the best.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\chemsetup[redox]{explicit-sign=true,explicit-zero-sign=true,format=\tiny }
\begin{document}
\ch{H}\ch{"\ox*[pos=top]{2,C}" "\ox*[pos=side,align=right]{-2,O}" O-}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With arabic numbers is the best result.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\chemsetup[redox]{roman = false,explicit-sign=true,explicit-zero-sign=true,format=\tiny }
\begin{document}
\ch{H}\ch{"\ox*[pos=top]{2,C}" "\ox*[pos=side,align=right]{-2,O}" O-}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help. But that is not where I want to go, since I really want to use roman letters and also for more elements in one molecule. I changed the example to make it clearer.

Comment: @Juch Hi, I understood your argument very well, and I admit even now that you are right. It is indeed very ugly. I have read the manual and did not see something for the spacing. Maybe I will write to the author of the package or send a message with the expectation that he will respond.

Answer (score 1):

I got slightly better results using the chemfig package.

With chemfig we can also draw the reduction/oxidation arrows

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{H\charge{90:2pt={\tiny II}}{C}\charge{90:2pt={\tiny -II}}{O}O^{-}}
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass[border=12mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}
  
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\tikzset{square arrow/.style={to path={-- ++(0,0.3) -| (\tikztotarget)}}}

\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemfig{@{c}\charge{90:2pt={\textcolor{red}{\tiny VII}}}{Mn}O^{-}_4} \arrow{->} \chemfig{@{d}\charge{90:2pt={\textcolor{red}{\tiny II}}}{Mn}}
\schemestop
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
    \draw[->,-stealth,square arrow,red,thick] ($(c.north)+(0.0em,2ex)$) to ($(d.north)+(-0.0em,2ex)$)node[above]{\parbox{2cm}{\hspace{-1.5cm}{\textcolor{blue}{REDUCTION \\}}}};
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]